# Failing to open a file when running through Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ifstream

I have the function

```
void foo()
  {
   std::string path = "Test.txt" ;
  std::ifstream file;
  file.open(path);
  if (file.good()) // if the file opened up 
  {
        std::cout << "YAY" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "ERROR!" << std::endl;
      getError();
  }
}
```

I have a file "Test.txt" in the folder where I have the .exe file .
Running the program direclly through the cmd follows a success in openning the file , but running the program through Visual studio fails to open the file .
I tried to open the file with a full path , but the result remained the same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Visual Studio's working directory is the project's folder (where you can usually see the code files and the project files), so make sure your file is there. The EXE is found at the `Debug` folder, which is irrelevant, as it is not Visual Studio's working directory.

You can change the working directory this way:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171340%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a file "Test.txt" in the folder where I have the .exe file

This is irrelevant. The process doesn't even know where the .exe file is!

What matters is the *current working directory* of the process, which may not be where the .exe was loaded from.

When debugging in Visual Studio, I believe that is the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 3):

The system runs the executable in some other directory (not the one that contains the exe-file). You can discover which one that is by creating a file:

```
void foo()
{
    std::ofstream hey("whatever");
}
```

Then look where the file was created. This is the directory where the system runs your exe-file.